# Авторизация в REST

Tags: авторизация, rest

У нас есть система Spring + Spring security, c пользователями и их ролями. 
Есть веб сервис(REST Jersey)

Каждой роли должны быть доступны определенные методы сервиса. Как правильно организовать авторизацию, для rest клиентов?

Вариант с передачей логина и пароля, получения токена и работа с токеном пока пропустим.

Какие есть сторонние решения, и какие из них наиболее удачные для решения задачи(OAuth2 и другие)?

Comment: Авторизация по REST?! %) Авторизуйте пользователя (не по REST), выдайте ему токен/ключ, отправляйте этот токен/ключ в каждом http-запросе к вашему сервису. Ах да! При авторизации сообщите вашему сервису полученный ключ/токен.

Comment: @uorypm, это классическое решение, я же хочу что то более интересное)